# In RegExr, why is regex OR in JavaScript sometimes not commutative?

Tags: regular-expressions

On https://regexr.com/, using the default JavaScript (Browser) engine, the languages $L(a^*|b^*)$ and $L(b^*|a^*)$ are not the same.
The first one matches only $a$'s and the second one $b$'s.

Is this a bug?
Or does the site something different than evaluating regular expressions, as I learned them in class?

Comment: If you try the regexp `(cre|rea)`, you'll find that the tool only reports one match (`cre`) within `create`: its does not handle overlaps. It has a bias on the left when detecting all the matches. Finding matches in a text, however, is not the same thing as considering the language of the regexp.

Comment: @chi your example does not explain why (a*|b*) does not match any b's . 

create is not in the language  of (cre|ate) that's why it makes sense that it does not match create, it does match cre and ate, though.

Comment: The tool you use finds matches, and does not directly consider the language of the regexp. If you use `a` as regexp, it will find a match within `bab`, even if `bab` is clearly not in the language of `a`. Using a regexp like `(a*|zzz)` will find a lot of matches using the empty string (in the language of `a*`), effectively ignoring the `zzz` part, as if the empty string "overlapped", as in the `cre|rea` example. Perhaps you can obtain what you want if you use as a regexp `^(a*|b*)$`, marking the beginning and the end of the string explicitly with `^` and `$` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic, since this seems to be a question purely about a specific regular expression library. PascalIv, you're correct that, in CS, "or" is commutative.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Actually the question is not specific to a particular library or language. It is partly specific to this particular _website_, because the way it presents things is a bit confusing, but there's also a general concept at play: matching vs searching. So I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug; it is rather the JavaScript RegEx engine tries to match as much of the first of the two expressions combined by the "|" operator as it can. Thus, instead of matching a word like "bbb" with as many "b"s as possible, it matches the pattern `a*` against the empty word (implicitly) at the beginning of "bbb". Granted, the RegExr interface does not highlight this properly, but that is more of a missing feature than a bug.

As mentioned in the comments, you should also be aware the engine tries to find (possibly) strings in the input text which *match* the pattern specified by the regex; the matches are what are highlighted by the RegExr interface. This is a different use of regexes than in formal language theory, in which regexes are used to specify formal languages, and in which an input (word) as a whole either matches the regex or not.

Caveat: If you are trying regexes verbatim from a formal languages class, you may run into trouble when trying to specify the empty word; the character `ε` is *not* interpreted as the empty word but as the Greek lowercase epsilon character instead. [This question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127384/what-is-a-regex-to-match-only-an-empty-string) contains some ways of correctly specifying (only) the empty word.

Warning number 2: If you write `L(a*|b*)` verbatim for your expression there, it is interpreted as a *capital $L$* followed by the pattern `(a*|b*)`, not as the language corresponding to the pattern `(a*|b*)`!

Comment: Nice answer. It could be better if the ideas in @Chi's comment can be included.  It could be better if you can make it explicit that "the tool" is one of most popular languages, JavaScript.

Comment: No, the tool doesn't use sed syntax, it uses Javascript syntax (by default). And it does apply the `*` operator to the previous parenthesised group.

Comment: @Gilles @Apass.Jack Modified answer so as to refer directly to the JS engine. My (admittedly incorrect) remark on `(a|b)*` being invalid was partly due to the dubious documentation on the RegExr site, which says `*` matches "0 or more of the preceding *token*"; of course, it should read "preceding *expression*" instead.